# why does it show that __init__ function should always return none?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.k=first
        self.p=last
        self.l=pay
        self.email=first+'.'+last+'@gmail.com'
        h= self.email
        return (h)

    def fullname(self):
        return ('{} {}'.format(self.k,self.p))

emp_1=Employee('Aditya','Shrivastava', 500000)
print(emp_1.fullname())`
```

Excepton:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:/Python/Programs/main.py", line 54, in <module>
    emp_1=Employee('corey','schafer',50000)
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'str'
```

Comment: Because `__init__` should always return `None`. Remove the `return (h)`.

Comment: *Why* does your `__init__` method return `self.email`?

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is called to set up the new, blank instance created. It always **must** return `None`. From the [`object.__init__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__):

> Because `__new__()` and `__init__()` work together in constructing objects (`__new__()` to create it, and `__init__()` to customize it), no non-`None` value may be returned by `__init__()`; doing so will cause a `TypeError` to be raised at runtime.

Returning `None` is the default for a function without a `return` statement; remove the `return (h)` from `__init__`:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.k=first
        self.p=last
        self.l=pay
        self.email=first+'.'+last+'@gmail.com'
```

You can access the `email` attribute after creating the instance, there is no need to return it.